# Regular expressions in boost python embedded in C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost-python

I'm trying to use python's Regular expression package `re` from within C++, within `boost.python` code. Here is an example code snippet in my C++ application:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>


Py_Initialize();
object main = import("__main__");
object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");

object ignored = exec(
        "import re\n"
        "def run():\n"
        "    rmatch = re.search(r'\d',r'hello3')\n"
        "    print rmatch\n"
        "\n"
        "print 'main module loaded'\n", main_namespace); 

object run_func = main.attr("run");
run_func(); 

Py_Finalize();
```

The regular expression should simply pick up the digit in the string `hello3`. This exact line of code works in Python, however in embedded python, `rmatch` is always `None`.

Would anyone be able to offer some insight as to why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the backslash:

```
"    rmatch = re.search(r'\\d',r'hello3')\n"
```

Remember it's getting processed by the C++ compiler first.  When Python gets hold of it, it will see `\d` an a linefeed instead of `\\d` and `\n`.  If you weren't using Python's raw strings (`r''`), you would have to write it as:

```
"    rmatch = re.search('\\\\d','hello3')\\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace `\d` with `\\d`.

PS
Why don't you just use boost.regex??

Comment: Good question.  Boost.Regex is much more powerful than Python's `re` flavor.

Comment: Thank you aleguna, that solution works! The reason is that I need to evaluate some expression in the embedded python function, so it's just more convenient to pass that expression to my python function and do the pattern matching and evaluation all together.